# Selenium: select first inner element

Tags: html, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I select all `<a>` elements inside all `<td>` elements

```
<td class="thread">
    <i class="ter green"></i>
    <a href="/forum/threads/12/">Something about...</a>
    <p class="info">Author</p>
</td>
```

I use the following:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.thread a"));
```

However, I'm getting much more elements than there should be. I guess that I must select only first `a` inside `td class="thread"`. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to find only single element, why are using `findElements` instead of `findElement`?? What do you want actually?? Do you want single `a` which have you provided in HTML???

Answer (score 2):

When you use the CSS Selector `td.thread a`, that reads any descendant `a` under `td.thread`. What you more likely want is `td.thread > a` which reads a child `a` of `td.thread`. It's still possible there are more than one `a` but you will likely get a lot fewer depending on the overall HTML.

[CSS Selector reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

```
thread = driver.find_element_by_class_name('thread')
correct_link = thread.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
print(correct_link)
>>> "/forum/threads/12/"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!